# Getting blank values for entitlement field in custom report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, entitlements

I have created a custom report type with account as parent object servicecontract ,contract line and entitlement as childs.
i have created a record on entitlement which has a lookup of contract  line and in contract line has a lookup of service contract and service contract has a lookup of account object

In the report of "entitlement with account" when i am displaying account fields along with entitlement fields i get entitlement fields displayed as blank.

Comment: Is the custom report type called 'entitlement with account' ?  or is this an OOB SFDC report type?

Comment: I got the issue.Total 3 lookup relationship is allowed in case of reporting.

Comment: really?  it should be four.  I did a custom report type on Order Products with lookup > Order > Opportunity > Account > ParentAccount.name before getting the too many lookup relationships error

Comment: Any docs or link for this governor limit ?

Comment: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_guidelines.htm